# High elbow carrying angle and becoming an astronaut

Tags: health, astronaut-recruitment

Would having a high carrying angle (cubitus valgus) disqualify a person from becoming an astronaut?

Comment: Have you looked at eg NASA's requirements? I think that may be the least of your worries: https://astronauts.nasa.gov/content/broch00.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worries. Cubitus valgus is only apparent when the hand is fully supinated (rotated so the thumb points away from the body). If the hand and elbow is in a physiologic functional position (elbow flexed 90 degrees, thumb pointing up) it disappears.

Cubitus valgus is an artifact of the traditional and arbitrary  "anatomical position" which anatomists have used to describe anatomy since the time of Leonardo Da Vinci.

Cubitus valgus increases the risk of ulnar neuropathy (tingling of the pinky and half the ring finger). If this occurs, simple surgery will relieve pressure on the nerve.

I'll write you a note for NASA

Comment: Thanks for the informative and lighthearted answer :]